# How to do a looping to Interpolate a huge Rainfall Time-series in GRASS GIS or R

Tags: grass-gis, r

In GRASS GIS I have access to a table in PostgreSQL Database with this structure:

Table Name: rainfall_time_series

Columns: id | year | month | day | value_mm | x | y | gauge_code

Setting g.region to the Watershed limits, I need create for each day one interpolated raster, representing the rainfall. This times-series is very huge, has 17 years, my question is: is it possible to do this operation with a looping? it is probably easier in R, but I'm newbie in this software.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross posted, as noted by @markusN:http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2013-February/067195.html

Answer (score 4):

The answer has been posted here:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2013-February/067195.html

Answer (score 2):

Doing this in R would require a number of building blocks:

- A function that extracts the unique days present in the database.
- A function that extracts the data for one day from the database into a `data.frame`. You can then transform this to a `SpatialPoints` object (see `sp` package documentation.
- A function that interpolates the data, and returns an interpolated grid for each day. This can be done using a host of interpolation methods in e.g. the `automap`/`gstat` package, the `fields` package, etc. For a more exhaustive list I refer to the CRAN Task view for Spatial data.

Once you have these blocks, the following pseudo code links them together:

```
unique_days = get_unique_days()
dat_list = lapply(unique_days, get_data_from_database) 
interpolated_maps = lapply(dat_list, interpolate_daily_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already solved your problem or not but here is a working example in `R`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sp) # for coordinates, CRS, proj4string, etc
library(gstat)
library(maptools)
#> Checking rgeos availability: TRUE

# Coordinates of gridded precipitation cells
precGridPts <- ("ID lat long
                1 46.78125 -121.46875
                2 46.84375 -121.53125
                3 46.84375 -121.46875
                4 46.84375 -121.40625
                5 46.84375 -121.34375
                6 46.90625 -121.53125
                7 46.90625 -121.46875
                8 46.90625 -121.40625
                9 46.90625 -121.34375
                10 46.90625 -121.28125
                11 46.96875 -121.46875
                12 46.96875 -121.40625
                13 46.96875 -121.34375
                14 46.96875 -121.28125
                15 46.96875 -121.21875
                16 46.96875 -121.15625
                ")

# Read precipitation cells
precGridPtsdf <- read.table(text = precGridPts, header = TRUE)

# Convert to a sp object
sp::coordinates(precGridPtsdf) <- ~long + lat # longitude first

# Add a spatial reference system (SRS) or coordinate reference system (CRS).   
# CRS database: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/
sp::proj4string(precGridPtsdf) <- sp::CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
str(precGridPtsdf)

#> Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
#>   ..@ data       :'data.frame':  16 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   .. ..$ ID: int [1:16] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>   ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 3 2
#>   ..@ coords     : num [1:16, 1:2] -121 -122 -121 -121 -121 ...
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:16] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "long" "lat"
#>   ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] -121.5 46.8 -121.2 47
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "long" "lat"
#>   .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
#>   ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
#>   .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# Convert to UTM 10N
utm10n <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 ellps=WGS84"
precGridPtsdf_UTM <- spTransform(precGridPtsdf, CRS(utm10n))

# Hypothetical annual precipitation data generated using Poisson distribution.  
precDataTxt <- ("ID PRCP2016 PRCP2017 PRCP2018
                1 2125 2099 2203
                2 2075 2160 2119
                3 2170 2153 2180
                4 2130 2118 2153
                5 2170 2083 2179
                6 2109 2008 2107
                7 2109 2189 2093
                8 2058 2170 2067
                9 2154 2119 2139
                10 2056 2184 2120
                11 2080 2123 2107
                12 2110 2150 2175
                13 2176 2105 2126
                14 2088 2057 2199
                15 2032 2029 2100
                16 2133 2108 2006"
)

precData <- read_table2(precDataTxt, col_types = cols(ID = "i"))

# Merge Prec data frame with Prec shapefile
precGridPtsdf <- merge(precGridPtsdf, precData, by.x = "ID", by.y = "ID")
precdf <- data.frame(precGridPtsdf)

# Merge Precipitation data frame with Precipitation shapefile (UTM)
precGridPtsdf_UTM <- merge(precGridPtsdf_UTM, precData, by.x = "ID", by.y = "ID")

region_extent <- structure(c(612566.169007975, 5185395.70942594, 639349.654465079, 
                             5205871.0782451), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"
                             ), c("min", "max")))

# Define the extent for spatial interpolation. Make it 4km larger on each direction 
x.range <- c(region_extent[1] - 4000, region_extent[3] + 4000)
y.range <- c(region_extent[2] - 4000, region_extent[4] + 4000)

# Create desired grid at 1km resolution
grd <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 1000), 
                   y = seq(from = y.range[1], to = y.range[2], by = 1000))   

# Convert grid to spatial object
coordinates(grd) <- ~x + y
# Use the same projection as boundary_UTM
proj4string(grd) <- "+proj=utm +zone=10 ellps=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84"
gridded(grd) <- TRUE

# Interpolate using Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW)
idw <- idw(formula = PRCP2016 ~ 1, locations = precGridPtsdf_UTM, newdata = grd)  
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]

# Clean up
idw.output = as.data.frame(idw)
names(idw.output)[1:3] <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Precipitation")

precdf_UTM <- data.frame(precGridPtsdf_UTM)

# Plot interpolation results
idwPlt1 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_tile(data = idw.output, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill = Precipitation)) +
  geom_point(data = precdf_UTM, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = PRCP2016), shape = 21, colour = "red") +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis() + 
  scale_size_continuous(name = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0))) 
idwPlt1
```

[image]

```r
### Now looping through every year 

list.idw <- colnames(precData)[-1] %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(., ~ idw(as.formula(paste(.x, "~ 1")), 
               locations = precGridPtsdf_UTM, newdata = grd)) 

#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]
#> [inverse distance weighted interpolation]

idw.output.df = as.data.frame(list.idw) %>% as.tibble()
idw.output.df

#> # A tibble: 1,015 x 12
#>    PRCP2016.x PRCP2016.y PRCP2016.var1.pred PRCP2016.var1.var PRCP2017.x
#>  *      <dbl>      <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1    608566.   5181396.              2114.                NA    608566.
#>  2    609566.   5181396.              2115.                NA    609566.
#>  3    610566.   5181396.              2116.                NA    610566.
#>  4    611566.   5181396.              2117.                NA    611566.
#>  5    612566.   5181396.              2119.                NA    612566.
#>  6    613566.   5181396.              2121.                NA    613566.
#>  7    614566.   5181396.              2123.                NA    614566.
#>  8    615566.   5181396.              2124.                NA    615566.
#>  9    616566.   5181396.              2125.                NA    616566.
#> 10    617566.   5181396.              2125.                NA    617566.
#> # ... with 1,005 more rows, and 7 more variables: PRCP2017.y <dbl>,
#> #   PRCP2017.var1.pred <dbl>, PRCP2017.var1.var <dbl>, PRCP2018.x <dbl>,
#> #   PRCP2018.y <dbl>, PRCP2018.var1.pred <dbl>, PRCP2018.var1.var <dbl>
```